# Kotlin function parameter generic interfacte type type mismatch

Tags: kotlin, types, interface, mismatch

I have some logic, similar like simpyfied below. 
Could someone explain me why execution of `fB()` showing mismatch?

```
interface SomeInterface<T> {
    fun showMe(aa: T)
    fun getOne(): T
}
```

```
interface Jsonizer {
    //something here
}
```

```
data class Template (val id: String): Jsonizer
```

```
object SomeImpl: SomeInterface<Template> {
    override fun showMe(aa: Template) {
        println("It $aa")
    }

    override fun getOne(): Template {
        return Template("91919191")
    }
}
```

```
fun fA() {
     // ERROR:
     // Required: SomeInterface<Jsonizer>
     // Found: SomeImpl
     fB(SomeImpl)
}

fun fB(service: SomeInterface<Jsonizer>) {
     val tmp1 = Template("112233") // assume it's generate by jsonizer
     service.showMe(tmp1)
     val tm2 = service.getOne()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `fB` requires a `SomeInterface<Jsonizer>` or one of its subtypes. `SomeImpl` is a subtype of `SomeInterface<Template>`, and `SomeInterface` is [invariant](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance) by its generic parameter, so `SomeInterface<Template>` is NOT a subtype of `SomeInterface<Jsonizer>`, although `Template` implements `Jsonizer`.

If you want `SomeInterface<Template>` to be a subtype of `SomeInterface<Jsonizer>`, you have to make `SomeInterface` covariant, but it's impossible because methods in covariant class can't take instance of that generic type as a parameter, and you have a method `showMe` that takes `T` as a parameter.

All that means that you should redesign your class architecture. For example, you may divide your `SomeInterface` into consumer and producer interfaces - consumer with method `showMe` and producer with method `getOne`, so you can make producer covariant and consumer contravariant and create different implementations for concrete subtypes of `Jsonizer` as you try in your code.

Answer (score 0):

- `SomeImpl` implements `SomeInterface<Template>`
- `fun fB` needs `SomeInterface<Jsonizer>`

If you want to make `fB` work, you could add *type* to the function:

`fun <T> fB(service: SomeInterface<T>)`